# When did Hades leave the Underworld?

Tags: greek, hades

> Although an Olympian, Hades preferred the Underworld and rarely left his kingdom.

As seen in my [source](http://www.greekmythology.com/Olympians/Hades/hades.html), Hades loved being in his "beloved" Underworld rather than being in the outside world and Olympus, like all other gods. Yet it says that Hades occasionally and rarely left the Underworld. Other than the time he kidnapped Persephone, when would Hades leave the Underworld?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hades leaving his cozy domain was rare, but not unheard of. Persephone wasn't the only reason that compelled him to take a trip above ground, she wasn't even his only kidnapping; [Leuce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leuce_%28mythology%29) suffered a similar fate.

Kidnappings aside, Hades was present when Hercules besieged Pylos, presumably collecting the souls of the dead:

> And so suffered monstrous Hades even as the rest a bitter arrow, when this same man, the son of Zeus that beareth the aegis, smote him in Pylos amid the dead, and gave him over to pains. But he went to the house of Zeus and to high Olympus with grief at heart, pierced through with pains;
>
> <sub>Source: [Hom. Il. 5.395](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Hom.+Il.+5.395&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134)</sub>

In another instance, Hades visits Olympus to bring accusations against [Asclepius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepius):

> [4.71.2] Consequently, the myth goes on to say, Hades brought accusation against Asclepius, charging him before Zeus of acting to the detriment of his own province, for, he said, the number of the dead was steadily diminishing, now that men were being healed by Asclepius.
>
> [4.71.3] So Zeus, in indignation, slew Asclepius with his thunderbolt, but Apollo, indignant at the slaying of Asclepius, murdered the Cyclopes who had forged the thunderbolt for Zeus; but at the death of the Cyclopes Zeus was again indignant and laid a command upon Apollo that he should serve as a labourer for a human being and that this should be the punishment he should receive fro him for his crimes.
>
> <sub>Source: [Bibliotheca historica, Diodorus Siculus](http://www.theoi.com/Text/DiodorusSiculus4D.html)</sub>