# Do all gods and goddesses live on Mount Οlympus?

Tags: greek, olympians, olympus

Do all Greek gods and goddesses live on Mount Olympus? Including minor ones like Echo, Narcissus, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

Both Hades and Poseidon, Zeus's brothers, prefer their own domains to Olympus. Hades lives in the [underworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_underworld) and Poseidon in the sea, near Euboea.

Hephaestus, another one of the *dodekatheon*, lived on Lemnos island after [Hera ejected him from Olympus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hephaestus#Fall_from_Olympus). In Thracian mythology, Ares prefered Mount Haimos in Thrace to Olympus.

Minor gods could also live elsewhere. A couple of examples from the *Odyssey* is Circe who lives on the mythical island [Aeaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeaea) and the nymph Calypso who lives in [Ogygia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogygia).

---

Further reading:

- [Why were the Greek Gods on Olympus?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/511/57)
- [Who lives in Mount Olympus usually?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/who-lives-in-mount-olympus-usually)
- [When did Hades leave the Underworld?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/496/when-did-hades-leave-the-underworld)